# Android: PrintStream.println(String) to .txt file contains <0x00> in java

Tags: java, android, println, printstream

I am trying to write some data to txt file using PrintStream.println. Some times it is working fine, But some times it is crashing the application. When i saw the result file, It contains <0x00> very huge amount of time. After that nothing printed in file.
Please find the below used code.

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("[MM/dd HH:mm:ss:SSS] ")
        Date date_value = new Date();
        String currentDateandTime = sdf.format(date_value);
        FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = new FileOutputStream("fileName", true);
        PrintStream plt_cbl_stream = new PrintStream(fileOutputStream);
        plt_cbl_stream.println(currentDateandTime);
        plt_cbl_stream.flush();
```

Can some one suggest me, What is the issue. Please find the details captured from created file.

Log captured from created file :

```
[20/01 15:30:24:865]
[20/01 15:30:24:8<0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00>68]
[20/01 15:30:24:872]
[20/01 15:30:24:877]
[20/01 15:30:24:892]
<0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00><0x00>
```

Comment: Show the log statements that produced that log.

Comment: "fileName". You should use a full path instead. This cannot work.

Comment: You are not closing the output stream.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. Yes, "File Name" will be the full path it is handled. File is creating successfully and it is containing the information also. But in the created file, I am seeing <0x00> so many times. Finally app got crashed. Please let me know, In the created file why <0x00> is coming.